# Azure Container Instances: how to expose same port for multiple container?

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I'm not sure what is port in Azure Container Instances and how it's used. I have 2 servers, that are both ASP.Net Core servers and must run together and talk to each other via sockets. This is YAML, that I used for deployment:

```yaml
apiVersion: 2019-12-01
location: westeurope
name: imgeneus-test
properties:

  imageRegistryCredentials:
    - server: imgeneusregistrytest.azurecr.io
      username: imgeneusregistrytest
      password: whatever

  restartPolicy: OnFailure

  containers:
  - name: imgeneus-login
    properties:
      image: imgeneusregistrytest.azurecr.io/imgeneus.login:latest
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1
          memoryInGb: 1
      ports:
      - port: 80 # 80 for web server, remove either this
      - port: 30800 # 30800 for tcp communication
    
  - name: imgeneus-world
    properties:
      image: imgeneusregistrytest.azurecr.io/imgeneus.world:latest
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1
          memoryInGb: 1
      ports:
      - port: 80 # 80 for web server, or remove that
      - port: 30810 # 30810 for tcp communication

  osType: Linux
  ipAddress:
      type: Public
      ports:
      - protocol: tcp
        port: 80
      - protocol: tcp
        port: 30800
      - protocol: tcp
        port: 30810

type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

But I can not open 80 port for both servers. Because even after opening only one 80 port, I navigate in browser to ACI ip and do not see anything there. What does it even mean this `ipAddress.ports` in YAML config? And If it's not possible to do with ACI what Azure service should I use instead?

Comment: https://bobcares.com/blog/docker-multiple-containers-same-port/ -Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map two services on same host port, i would suggest to use reverse proxy like ***Traefik*** or ***Nginx, HAProxy, Envoy.*** Multiple containers for this service are created on a single host, the port will clash.
The reverse proxy will listen the host port 80 at that point it forward to a particular docker container on port which are not mapped to the host depending a few characterized rules like aliases, URL path.

> What does it even mean this `ipAddress.ports` in YAML config

you can use ACI ip itself which means The IP address type of the container group accepted values of Private, Public and list of ports to open. Space-separated list of ports default value: [80] of [az container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest)

And also, To make a server socket [`listen()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html) on a certain address, you need to explicitly [`bind()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) it to an interface and port. Binding a socket to an *(interface, port)* pair was an exclusive process recheck your permission and services.

For your Reference:

https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/multiple-containers-same-port-reverse-proxy/